# pkg.tar.xz file - how to unpack on a Unix or Windows system?

Tags: windows, unix

I am a newbie Unix user. I have a file whose extension is `pkg.tar.xz`. How can I unpack this file on Windows or Unix?

I can use Cygwin but I'm not sure which utility I'd need to use. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to unpack it in windows?

Comment: I see that you accepted my answer, but if your file's extension is really what you say it is, you should have accepted Bradley's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got Cygwin installed, then create a new directory and execute the following from within it:

```
tar zxvf FILE.tgz
```

If the person who produced the file was polite, it will contain its own top-level directory. If the person was impolite, it might contains lots of files, and you want a directory to contain them all.

Comment: The z in that won't work as it's an xz, not a gz. Meaning it's been packaged with LZMA instead of gzip.

Comment: @Bradley - my bad, I misread the OP.

Comment: I did at first as well. :)

Comment: @upvoter - thanks, but Bradley's answer is the correct one

Answer (score 13):

In cygwin, you can use the following command at the command line: `tar xvJf pkg.tar.xz`. EDIT: note that that's a capital J, which is the flag for LZMA (xz), **not** a lower-case j, which is the flag for bzip2.

In Windows, I would recommend using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

Comment: Does this also run the program?

Answer (score 2):

Googling around:

> 7-Zip supports xz as of version 9.04 beta

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz)

Answer (score 1):

That is the Arch Linux package extension; like deb for 'ubuntu, debian or mint; or rpm for suse, RHEL, and centOS.

`tar -xf *.tar.xz` works for simple unzip.

You don't get anything human readable.

```
.pkg.tar.xz IS NOT SOURCE CODE.
To actually use it like a binary: in arch linux
sudo pacman -U ~/downloads/packages/packagename-ve.rsi.onnumber.pkg.tar.xz
proceed? [yes/n]
Installing packagename.versi.on 
[######################################]DONE!
[username@archlinux] $
```